# How can I keep a mouseover'd DIV visible via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseleave, mouseenter

Okay.. a bit complicated of a question. I have a DIV that appears when you mouseover a TR.

```
$(".alignment_tr").hover( function() {
    console.log( "alignmententer" + triggerMouseover );
        var tid = $(this).find( ".hidden_inp_selected_alignment" ).val();
        var element = $(this);

        if( ! element.hasClass( "mouseover-tooltip" ) )
        {
            $.ajax( {
                url: Drupal.settings.jstools.basePath + "?q=search/mouseover_info",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { "tid": tid },
                success: function( response ) {
                        $(".mouseover-tooltip .top-level").html( response.genre );
                        $(".mouseover-tooltip .second-level").html( response.name );
                        $(".mouseover-tooltip .description").html( response.description );
                        $(".mouseover-tooltip").css( {
                            left: element.position().left + ( element.width() * 0.75 ),
                            top: element.position().top - element.height() / 2,
                        } );
                        if( $(".mouseover-tooltip").css( "display" ) == "none" )
                        {
                            $(".mouseover-tooltip").fadeIn();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    },
    function() {
    console.log( "alignmentleave" + triggerMouseover );
        setTimeout( fadeMouseover, 5000 );
    }
);
```

I'm trying to get it so that when you mouse over the DIV, it doesn't just disappear. Any tips?

**CLARIFICATION**
Right now, when you mouseover the TD, the DIV appears. I rigged it so that when you mouseover the DIV, it stays (used to disappear). But now the DIV doesn't disappear when your mouse leaves the TR AND leaves the DIV.

Comment: "I'm trying to get it so that when you mouse over the DIV, it doesn't just disappear" did you mistype that? Right now it appears when you mouse over, and you want it so that it doesn't just disappear?

Comment: See "CLARIFICATION" above. My mistake for not being clear.

Comment: A tip: You could change the line `if($(".mouseover-tooltip").css("display") == "none")` into this, more readable, line: `if($(".mouseover-tooltip").is(":hidden"))`

Comment: I would suggest reading a bit about JavaScript event bubbling and the jQuery events hover, mouseenter and mouseleave. I found this that might interest you on the latter: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm

Comment: He could make it even more readable by deleting it. fadein doesn't do anything for visible elements.

Comment: Is there anything significant in fadeMouseover? I feel like that's where you should have you're code to fade out the tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `div` is absolutely positioned, which I believe it is, place it within the `tr`.  In that way, your mouse being over the div will count as it being over the `td` as well.  That way your mouse being over the `div` or the `tr` will not trigger `mouseleave`.

A fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mHCNj/1/

Comment: Interesting.. but the DIV is one element. There are different TR's that all activate the DIV.

Comment: you can inject it into the relevant tr as needed.

Comment: @Shamoon I added a fiddle to my answer to illustrate this.